# How can I use env variables in this buildspec.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild

I've been building out this `buildspec.yml` file to configure my CodeBuild integration and while I can inject variables everywhere else in the script, it fails when I try to repeat the pattern in the `printf` section shown below. I'm out of ideas in regards to setting it up and I'm curious if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"<HOW_TO_PLACE_VAR_HERE>","imageUri":"<HOW_TO_PLACE_VAR_HERE>"}]' $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json

       ^ how would I inject variables here? the $PATTERN doesn't work.
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
    - 'imagedefinitions.json'
  name: s3-to-s3-latest-build.zip
  discard-paths: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> printf '[{"name":"<HOW_TO_PLACE_VAR_HERE>","imageUri":"<HOW_TO_PLACE_VAR_HERE>"}]' $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json

Firstly, you are sending the output to a file, so probably you have not checked the actual contents.

Secondly, you can go with `echo` statement as you have used elsewhere

> echo '[{"name":"'$IMAGE_REPO_NAME'"}]'

you can still send the contents to a file by redirecting the stdout to required file

> echo '[{"name":"'$IMAGE_REPO_NAME'"}]' > imagedefinitions.json